# Granting X11 xauth permessions to a non sudoer

Tags: 14.04, ssh, xorg, sshd, x11-forwarding

I have several non-sudoers on an Ubuntu machine that needs to access to `X11 forwarding`. However, I can't seem to find a workaround to pass `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication` error as everytime the sudoer accounts logs out, the `MAGIC-COOKIE` will be set to another, thus the non-sudoers will lose their correct `xauth list`.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Using a sudoer account I execute commands as :

```
sudo su - nonSudoerUser -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
NONE
sudo su - nonSudoerUser -c 'xauth list'
NONE
sudo su - nonSudoerUser -c 'firefox &'
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication
```

Now checking the sudoer side:

```
xauth list
NAME/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c1ed9d514d3c1ca1166d20b3edd794b6
```

Copy that to the non-sudoer ~/.Xauthority:

```
sudo su - nonSudoerUser -c 'xauth add NAME/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c1ed9d514d3c1ca1166d20b3edd794b6'
```

Check if it's working:

```
sudo su - nonSudoerUser -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
localhost:10.0
```

Now, log out/in and recheck sudoers list and we see the `MAGIC-COOKIE` is changed and the non-sudoer can't connect to X11 anymore.

On my sshd_config I have:

```
Host *
X11Forwarding yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

Also, I tried:

```
$sudo xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

Without any success. Can anyone clarify this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"access to X11 forwarding (separate on their own $DISPLAY)"*? Normally that's something that's set up by a remote client (such as invoking `ssh` with the `-X` or `-Y` option) and doesn't depend on `sudo` status at all.

Comment: @steeldriver, they use `ssh -XY non-sudoerUser@IP` to connect, but they can not have an X11 session run. This error returns: `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication`